# combination of multiple AND , NOT IN condition is not working properly in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi i write the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `product`
WHERE (`color` IN ('black'))
   OR (`pattern` IN ('pattern-1', 'pattern-2', 'pattern-3'))
  AND `p_category` LIKE '%Blind%'
  AND id NOT IN('20', '19', '18', '17', '11')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

but for some reason it showing the product with id `'20', '19', '18', '17', '11'`

i think this information is enough for to solve this .

**Update**

Here i cannot figure out where i need to change . Here i am using ajax .  All the operation is take place in that page .  Post variable getting to ajax called page the operation i performed is

```
$keyword_array= ( [keyword] => Array ( 
                    [0] => color*black 
                    [1] => pattern*pattern-1
                    [2] => pattern*pattern-2
                    [3] => pattern*pattern-3 ) 
        [y_id] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 20
                    [1] => 19
                    [2] => 18
                    [3] => 17
                    [4] => 11 ) 
       [category] => Romex Blind );


       foreach ( $keyword_array as $value) {
            list($before, $after) = explode('*', $value);
            $elements[$before][] = $after;
        }

        $parts = [];

        foreach ($elements as $column => $values) {
            $parts[] = "(`$column` IN ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "'))";
        }

        $appear=implode("', '", $_POST['y_id']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $parts). "  AND `p_category` LIKE '%".$_POST['category']."%' AND id NOT IN('{$appear}') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Please tell what is the error in this query .

Comment: Query is working as coded - Or condition is more powerful than not in - what was your intent overall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make breakets around the or expresseion:

```
SELECT *
FROM `product`
WHERE (`color` IN ('black')
   OR `pattern` IN ('pattern-1', 'pattern-2', 'pattern-3'))
  AND `p_category` LIKE '%Blind%'
  AND id NOT IN('20', '19', '18', '17', '11')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

**UPDATE**
try

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (" . implode(' OR ', $parts). ")  AND `p_category``
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend . It is working fine . Your answer is perfect . Really thank you fro your effort .

Answer (score -1):

You may write query like this

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE (color = 'black' OR pattern IN ('pattern-1', 'pattern-2', 'pattern-3')) AND p_category LIKE '%Blind%' AND id NOT IN (20, 19, 18, 17, 11) ORDER BY id
```

You may use only OR if there are two or more conditions and just need one answer like

in you case you query seems wrong data will get

Comment: You Change the complete logic